# Docker compose - stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, portainer

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which is bringing up 5 different containers. In order to actually bring them up, I am using a `docker-composer up -d`.

I like to have some sort of GUI, so I am using Portainer to see my containers, and what I have noticed is that Portainer container list actually has one more field which I've never seen in the `docker ps`, and that is `stack`.

Now I've read about stacks in [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part5/) but still don't quite get one thing. My `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` say nothing about stacks, however when I bring my containers up, they are all labeled as stack being the folder where my Docker configuration resides.

What is the usage of this other than classifying that that set of containers belong to the same stack? Can the property be manipulated so that I assign it my personal naming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

It's a naming convention by Portainer. They are using the term `stack` both for *Docker Swarm* and *Docker Compose* in their [docs](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/templates.html).

---

**Original post:**

*Docker Compose* and *Docker Stack* can both be controlled by a `docker-compose.yml`

From [Docker Compose vs Docker Stack](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-23-docker-compose-vs-docker-stack) by Nick Janetakis:

> [Docker Compose](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/get-to-know-dockers-ecosystem#docker-compose) is an official tool that helps you manage your Docker containers by letting you define everything through a `docker-compose.yml` file.
>
> `docker stack` is a command that's embedded into the [Docker CLI](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/get-to-know-dockers-ecosystem#docker-cli). It lets you manage a cluster of Docker containers through [Docker Swarm](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/get-to-know-dockers-ecosystem#docker-swarm).

---

> It just so happens both Docker Compose and the `docker stack` command support the same `docker-compose.yml` file with **slightly different features**.
>
> In some cases, certain features that only work with `docker stack` are ignored by Docker Compose, and likewise, unsupported features of Docker Compose are ignored by the `docker stack` command.
>
> For example, the `deploy` property is ignored by Docker Compose and `depends_on` is ignored by `docker stack`. There are other differences too. You can find them out by checking out the [official Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). It will call out Compose or Stack specific properties.
>
> This allows you to define a single `docker-compose.yml` that works for both Docker Compose and `docker stack` which is a nice quality of life improvement if you happen to use Docker Compose in development and Docker Swarm in production.

Comment: Sure, but why is stack created initially if I never explicitly said it so?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example to test it? Also, maybe it's a naming convention used by portainer and it's confusing...

Comment: It looks like they are using terms like *Swarm stack* and *Compose stack* in their [docs](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/templates.html).

Comment: Ah yes, I noticed I can change that by providing a `-p` parameter in `docker-compose` command. How ever I name the project, that "compose stack" is then assigned.

Comment: Yes that's just portainer's naming convention: compose `stack` is in the general sense like full`stack` while swarm stack is the `docker stack`